# Why does the Apex compiler think I'm trying to call a function with a void signature?

Tags: apex, json, class

I have built this class, in the attempt to pass some JSON from JavaScript to Apex:

```apex
public with sharing class QueryDefinition {
    public Integer lim;
    public Integer offset;
    public String searchTerm;
    public Boolean getCount;
    public List<String> queries;

    public static void testSerialization() {
        Decimal n = (Decimal)JSON.deserialize('100.1', Decimal.class);
        System.assertEquals(n, 100.1);
        System.debug(n);
        String json = '{ "limit": 50, "offset": 0, "searchTerm": "NAP", "getCount": "true", "queries": [ "Status__c = \'NAP\' AND NAP_Confirmed__c = FALSE", "STATUS__C IN (\'OFF\', \'RET\') AND Source__c = \'Loan Officer\'" ] }';
        QueryDefinition query = (QueryDefinition)JSON.deserialize(json, QueryDefinition.class);
        System.debug(query);
    }
}
```

When I use anonymous Apex deploy this class, I get the following error:

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void deserialize(String, System.Type)
from the type String (13:55)
```

Why does the compiler think I'm expecting `void` from the function? I'm attempting to cast it to `QueryDefinition`. How can I create a custom class that can be deserialized from JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apex in general is not case-sensitive. Because of that, when you defined your `String json` variable, it caused you to "shadow" the JSON class.

The hint that this is what's happening is in the error message. "Method does not exist ... *from the type String*"

You can fix this by using the fully qualified name for the JSON class, `System.JSON.deserialize()`, or by renaming your `String json` variable to something else like `jsonInput`.

Renaming the variable is probably the better approach, in my opinion.

Comment: OK, I think I officially hate case-insensitive languages. :) I'm so used to `JSON`, `json`, etc., being unique identifiers in Python and most languages.